# Change framerate of mp4 video without reencoding using mp4box and piping

Tags: command-line, video, input, output, pipe

I'd basically like to do what [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370692/how-to-change-the-framerate-of-a-video-without-reencoding) asked for. Using the lines of Mitch I get a perfect result. I'd now love to use the output of mp4box directly as input of mp4box again (to make one command out of these two lines) and came across pipes and redirectors. Is there any possibility of getting the functionality of those two commands into just one by using pipes or something similair?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can convince `mp4box` to both read the input video file from `STDIN`; and write the output video file to `STDOUT` or use some user-specified file descriptor (see `mp4box`'s documentation), pipes do not apply. However, you could put both of those commands (or similar) into a shell script, and issue the two commands by typing the shell script's name.